# auto encode iFrame URL - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url, iframe, decode, encode

There is a werid issue only happening on some of the chromes. my coworker and I have the same version of Chrome, but her chrome does auto decode the encoded URL for the iFrame.

For example, we expect the URL for the iFrame to be encoded as ?xxxx
https://.......'%3Fparam1%3Dx1%26param2....
But for her Chrome it is already encoded, and the UI in iFrame does not and cannot expect. It needs the encoded url.
for her:
https://....?param1=x1&param2=x2 etc.

What is different for us? why the decode happens in hers?

Comment: What URL? What iframe? Where is this all happening?

Comment: so there is a portal, it has an iFrame that opens our new UI. That new UI expects the link encoded. But Chrome for some reason does decode

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there was no issue with the browser. The Chrome had cached the old javascript code which was not encoding the url. And clearing cache was not helping. By restarting the PC, the correct function showed up and iframe showed the encoded url. So, was not a mistake for Chrome really.